# How to create a criteria under specific folder in apiato?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, apiato

I want to create a criteria file in specified path, can you please help me..

**Path**:-
App->ship->criteria->eloquent

I am trying with

`php artisan make: criteria someName --path=App\ship\criteria\Eloquent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no specific commands to create a criteria in particular locations.

just run the following command and change the location of file manually into required location and change the `namespace` path also.

```
php artisan make:criteria sample
```